# How do I kill all a user's processes using their UID

Tags: c, linux, proc

I want to kill all running processes of a particular user from either a shell script or native code on a Linux system.

Do I have to read the /proc directory and look for these?

Any ideas? Is there a dynamic mapping of the pids under UIDs in Linux? Isn't this in the proc?

If not, then where is this list maintained? Should I read from it? Also where is the static list of all UIDs in the system so I can validate this this user exists and then proceed to kill all processes running under it?

Comment: Do you want a tool to do this (pkill, slay, others exist), or do you want to write it yourself? If the former, the superuser stack exchange site is probably better. If the latter, scanning /proc and making a note for all processes by a specific user is the way to go. The source code for the pkill utility would, for example, show how to do that.

Comment: Could you clarify what this question was about in light of @LarsWirzenius's comment? Thanks!

Comment: @Caleb: I wanted to kill processes by reading the /proc as I didn't know of any tool doing it. Also now I find that other than "kill", "pkill", "skill" etc are not available on my system. In that case I guess I have to look at shell script alternatives to read the /proc and figure out a way to get processes under one user. Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding “the static list of all UIDs … so I can validate this this user exists”: there is no such thing as validating a user ID. User names come from a database, but user IDs are whatever a process running `setuid()` chooses.

Comment: step 1 :
**top -u username** step 2 :
**Press k to kill process accordingly**

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Use `pkill -U UID` or `pkill -u UID` or username instead of UID. Sometimes `skill -u USERNAME` may work, another tool is [`killall -u USERNAME`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall).

[Skill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/skill) was a linux-specific and is now outdated, and [pkill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) is more portable (Linux, Solaris, BSD).

pkill allow both numberic and symbolic UIDs, effective and real http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html

> pkill  -  ... signal processes based on name and other attributes
>
> ```
>     -u, --euid euid,...
>          Only match processes whose effective user ID is listed.
>          Either the numerical or symbolical value may be used.
>     -U, --uid uid,...
>          Only match processes whose real user ID is listed.  Either the
>          numerical or symbolical value may be used.
> ```

Man page of skill says is it allowed only to use username, not user id: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/skill.1.html

> skill, snice ...  These tools are obsolete and unportable.  The command syntax is poorly defined.  Consider using the killall, pkill
>
> ```
>   -u, --user user
>          The next expression is a username.
> ```

killall is not marked as outdated in Linux, but it also will not work with numberic UID; only username: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html

> killall - kill processes by name
>
> ```
>    -u, --user
>          Kill only processes the specified user owns.  Command names
>          are optional.
> ```

I think, any utility used to find process in Linux/Solaris style /proc (procfs) will use full list of processes (doing some readdir of `/proc`). I think, they will iterate over `/proc` digital subfolders and check every found process for match.

To get list of users, use [`getpwent`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) (it will get one user per call).

[skill](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blame/master/skill.c) (procps & procps-ng) and [killall](https://sourceforge.net/p/psmisc/code/ci/master/tree/src/killall.c) (psmisc) tools both uses [`getpwnam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html) library call to parse argument of `-u` option, and only username will be parsed. `pkill` (procps & procps-ng) [uses both atol and getpwnam](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/625d0809daa5b666d9f5834bebcdc458799221f3/pgrep.c#L265) to parse `-u`/`-U` argument and allow both numeric and textual user specifier.

Comment: pkill is not obsolete. It may be unportable outside Linux, but the question was about Linux specifically.

Comment: to get the list of users use the one liner: getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'

Comment: what about I give a command like: "kill -ju UID" from C system() call?

Comment: Yes, you can. Not a kill, but `pkill -u UID -##`, where UID is number user id and `##` is signal number.

Comment: @osgx: Sadly, kill is the only utility I have :(

Comment: is it an embedded linux? you have no skill, pkill and killall? Even busybox embedded shell has pkill and killall.

Comment: `killall -u USERNAME` worked like charm

Comment: has skill changed now, as my skill expects a username with the -u flag, not the user ID: -u  The next argument is a username.

Comment: @LaurenceCope, Thanks, I updated the answer. No, skill of procps-ng was not changed, only text username for `skill -u username` is allowed. Tool uses `getpwnam` libcall (it is defined only for user name, not for id) to parse `-u` argument for more than 5 years https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blame/master/skill.c `case 'u': .... passwd_data = getpwnam(optarg);` Same for skill in classic procps: http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/skill.c?revision=1.15&view=markup.

Comment: `skill -u username` saved my day

Comment: is there one that doesn't kill my ssh connection to the server I'm connected to? `pkill -U user` kills me and logs me out.

Answer (score 10):

If you pass -1 as the process ID argument to either the [`kill` shell command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/kill.html) or the [`kill` C function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html), then the signal is sent to all the processes it can reach, which in practice means all the processes of the user running the `kill` command or syscall.

```
su -c 'kill -TERM -1' bob
```

In C (error checking omitted):

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    setuid(uid);
    signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);
    kill(-1, SIGTERM);
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution. `kill -1` avoids any race-conditions but please read the following article for additional information: https://lwn.net/Articles/754980/

Answer (score 8):

If the pkill function is unavailable on your UNIX / Linux distribution you could run the following command as the root user:

```
ps -ef | grep username | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

where username is the user who's processes you want to delete

Comment: or just the `pkill -U username`.

Answer (score 2):

```
pgrep -U username|xargs kill -9
```

Comment: If you have `pgrep` you also have `pkill`. Why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

This has worked nicely for me.  You can find all the pid's of the processes by username by doing `ps U <username>` and go from there.  Try this:

```
ps U <username> | cut -d " " -f 1 | xargs kill
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Kill all process for user.
2. Wait 2 seconds.
3. Update username and home directory.

```
 killall -u user; sleep 2; usermod -l newuser -d /home/newuser -m user
```

Comment: Why the last step with `usermod`?

Comment: modify a user's account

Comment: You don't have to use `usermod` to kill a user's processes. Please explain that step further and why you think it's necessary.