# Stop all processes by a user: children of supervisord are still running

Tags: process, users, kill, supervisord

I'm trying to delete a user but it keeps saying that user is currently used by process ID x

I tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452081/kill-all-processes-for-a-given-user) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/how-do-i-kill-all-a-users-processes-using-their-uid), nothing works, how do I kill all the process by a certain user in order to delete the account?

After running `su user -c 'kill -s KILL -- -1'`, I still see some processes:

```
[root@cdp ~]# ps -fljHu webdev
F S UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S webdev   30031 26903 30031 26903  0  80   0 - 54756 poll_s 18:35 ?        00:00:00 /opt/site/venv/bin/python /opt/site/venv/bin/gunicorn website.wsgi:appl
1 S webdev   30045 30031 30031 26903  0  80   0 - 69156 poll_s 18:35 ?        00:00:00   /opt/site/venv/bin/python /opt/site/venv/bin/gunicorn website.wsgi:ap
1 S webdev   30046 30031 30031 26903  0  80   0 - 69158 poll_s 18:35 ?        00:00:00   /opt/site/venv/bin/python /opt/site/venv/bin/gunicorn website.wsgi:ap
1 S webdev   30047 30031 30031 26903  0  80   0 - 69160 poll_s 18:35 ?        00:00:00   /opt/site/venv/bin/python /opt/site/venv/bin/gunicorn website.wsgi:ap
```

Process 26903 is `supervisord`.

Comment: What's process 26903?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it's `Supervisord`

Comment: @Fischer `supervisord` automatically restarts processes and is probably running as root. You need to kill that first.